# Error when composing validators

Tags: angular

I'm building own form controls.
In loop of fields I'm adding `FormControls` to `FormGroup`. But when I try to define validators composition it throws me `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

Here is example app. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1j7x8p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-input.component.ts
Open console.
With `Validators.compose([Validators.required])` all works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you have got very interesting case.

So lets dive in what your code is doing

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <my-input *ngFor="let field of fields" [formGroup]="formGroup" [field]="field"></my-input>
</form>
```

where

```
 formGroup = new FormGroup({}, { updateOn: 'submit' });

 fields = [
      { id: 'id', name: 'name' },
      { id: 'id2', name: 'name2', validators: { required: true } },
 ]
```

Here for each existing field in your `fields` in your `AppComponent` , Angular is rendering input field, and in the process of doing so it also fills the `formGroup` object in `AppComponent`

So in the beginning you have a **valid** `formGroup`, which is empty and **valid**. After iterating trough your `fields` collection for the first time, inside your `my-input.component` you are inserting a form control in the `formGroup` that is passed from the parent component in the `ngOnInit` life hook in the child component (While still being in the `ngOnInit` life hook of the parent element).

```
 If (!this.formGroup.contains(this.field.id)) {
    this.formGroup.addControl(
    this.field.id,
    New FormControl(
      undefined, 
      this.getValidators(this.field.validators)
    )
  );
}
```

You are also adding error validators based on the `fields` input coming from the parent via the following function.

```
private getValidators(validators) {
  if (validators) {
    const ngValidators = [];
    for (const validatorName in validators) {
      if (Validators[validatorName]) {
        ngValidators.push(Validators[validatorName]);
      }
    }
    return Validators.compose(ngValidators);
  }
  return Validators.compose([]);
}
```

At this point you have rendered the first input and filled the `formGrop` with one form control, **which doesn't have any validators** (because there were none in the field's configuration).

So now before entering the `my-input.component`for second time via the `ngFor` our `formGroup` is **valid** and we are still in the **`ngOnInit`** life hook of `AppComponent` (in other words the parent).

After we enter the `my-input.component` component for second time, we see that the second objects, from `fields` has `validators` property. Thanks to that we are adding now new formControl to the `formGroup` that we are using (from within `my-input.component`) and this form control, now has a required validator, but also it has no value inside, which immediately triggers the added validator, and makes the `formGroup` **invalid**. By doing so we are **changing the state** of the `formGroup`'s `Valid` property and that triggers the `expression changed after it has been checked` error.

I hope that helped you out.

Comment: Question is why is it working with Validators.compose([Validators.required])?

Comment: Because when you are using  // Validators.compose([Validators.required]) // this works  you are placing the validator on all form controls. If you place the `Validators.compose([Validators.required])` inside the `if(validators)` it will still throw `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.